# Local security setting will not persist: Administrator account status

Tags: group-policy, windows-10, entra-id

I'm trying to disable the local admin on my workstation. I load local group policy editor and navigate to `Computer Config -> Windows Settings -> Security settings -> Local Policies -> Security options`, and I **disable** the `Accounts: Administrator account status`. I then exit the editor and reload it but the setting has returned to **enabled**.

**This PC is connected to *Azure ActiveDirectory*.** I can't see any errors in the Event Viewer.

My goal is to stop the local admin account logging in automatically when Windows starts up, which is what it's doing currently.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the user account in Local Users and Groups?

Comment: This worked, thanks! Note: you have to hunt for that control panel on Windows 10 as it no longer comes up in search. http://www.isunshare.com/windows-10/5-ways-to-open-local-users-and-groups-in-windows-10.html

Comment: Open File Explorer... Right click "This PC"... select "Manage" from the context menu.